# Not found SetResourceReference in new Groupbox I'm creating in code behind

Tags: wpf, templates, powerbuilder

I want to set a reference to a Template in a groupbox I'm creating in the code behind.In a example I found, they mostly use SetResourceReference method. However, I see that this method doesn't seem to exist on the new Groupbox property in creating. 
XAML:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupBox" x:Key="GBTemplate">
```

Code Behind:

```
groupbox gb_plat
gb_plat= create GroupBox
gb_plat.SetResourceReference(Groupbox.TemplateProperty,"GBTemplate")
```

This method have come out with 2 errors,
1.Undefined variable: TemplateProperty
2. Can't find element SetResourceReference

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the control template for your groupbox then you will have to do:

```
 gb_plate.Template = Resources["GBTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
```

Comment: Thanks, but now come out with errors: Syntax Error:"Control Template" and syntax Error near 'Template'

Comment: are you coding in C# or VB.net?